# How many ordered $n$-tuples of $(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{2n})$

Tags: combinatorics

Give the postive integer $n$,and such $\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{2n}\}=\{1,2,3,\cdots,2n\}$,and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\max\{a_{i},i\}=3n^2+n$$

How many ordered $n$-tuples of $(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{2n})$

I only know that the answer is $(n!)^2$. How can I find it?

I tried
$$\max\{a_{i},i\}=\dfrac{a_{i}+i+|a_{i}-i|}{2}$$
so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}[(a_{i}+i)+|a_{i}-i|]=6n^2+2n$$
so we have
$$2\cdot\dfrac{(1+2n)\cdot 2n}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{2n}|a_{i}-i|=6n^2+2n$$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}|a_{i}-i|=2n^2$$

Comment: Is the index on the tuple supposed to run to $n$ or $2n$? If it runs to $n$, what are $a_{n+1},\dots,a_{2n}$ in the set that you mention, and what are you summing over?

Comment: sorry, run to $2n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{3n^2+n}{2}=(n+1)+(n+2)+\dots+2n$, so that $3n^2+n$ is the maximum this sum can ever reach. It follows that $\{a_1,a_2\dots,a_n\}=\{n+1,n+2,\dots,2n\}$ and that $\{a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\dots,a_{2n}\}=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and that there are no other restrictions on the tuple. Thus you have $n!$ ways to order the first half of the sequence and $n!$ ways to order the second half, for a total of $(n!)^2$.